# ArcGIS Server 10.0, Rest Service not showing relashionship class

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.0, rest, relationship-class

It's the first time that I am using Relationship Classes for a web mapping project.  Everything seems to be set-up properly, meaning I can get the related info out of ArcMap and ArcCatalog when viewing the map service.  But the REST service won't show me the related information.

---

I published a service with only my parcel layer in it and still having the same issue.

My Feature Class, Table and Relationship Class are stored in SDE.
I'm using ArcGIS 10.0 SP4 (Server, Desktop and SDE).

Comment: How are you testing the REST service?  Is this service published to the Internet?

Comment: Looking at the Rest Endpoint I should be getting something like that http://sampleserver3.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Petroleum/KSPetro/MapServer/0  and I'm not

Comment: And sorry @mwalker The service in internal only.

Comment: After further investigation, I recreated my featureclass, table and relationship and it worked.  So I don't know if it was an error in SDE or what but now it's working.